# Help finding the general solution of a (partial?) differential equation.

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I've been asked to find the general solution of the differential equation:
$$
    y^{'} - y^3 = y^3e^x\qquad\text{, satisfying}\quad y(0)=1
$$

To solve it I did the following:
$$
    y^{'} - y^3 = y^3e^x \Rightarrow  y^{'} = y^3 + y^3e^x\qquad\text{(1)}\\
    \int{\frac {dy}{dx}} \; =\int{y^3 + y^3e^x \; dx}\qquad\text{(2)}\\
    y=xy^3+y^3e^x+C\qquad\text{(3)}\\
    y(0)=1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 1=(0)(1)+(1)(1)+C \quad \Rightarrow \quad C=0\qquad\text{(4)}\\
    \therefore\; y=xy^3+y^3e^x \qquad\text{(5)}\\
$$

But I think I might be wrong... Is this correct? If not, could someone please walk me through what I need to do or at least point me in the right direction?

.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step $\int y^3\, dx = xy^3$ is wrong because $y$ is a function of $x$, not a constant.
 You can rewrite your ODE (it is not a partial differential equation) as

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^3(1+e^x).$$

This is a *separable* differential equation.  The RHS is the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$.  You can treat the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as if it were a fraction (even though it's not) and separate variables to get:

$$\frac{dy}{y^3} = (1+e^x) dx$$

Slap an integral sign on both sides of the equation, integrate, choose your constant of integration so $y(0)=1$, and solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ if possible.

Any decent text on differential equations will have a section on separable equations. I hope you have one.

Also, you are solving an initial value problem, so I don't think your goal is actually to find the "general solution".  The phrase "general solution" is generally used when there is no initial condition.